# Avrcp configuration for Bluez

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, avrcp

I have been trying to bring avrcp control up from my ubuntu desktop to control the music played on my mobile. 
Bluetooth Stack Used: Bluez 4.101

But i am not seeing the intefaces org.bluez.MediaTransport or Org.Bluez.Control enable on Dbus.
What configuration i need to edit in order to get these interfaces available ?\
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge AVRCP controller role (CT) is only partially implemented in Bluez 4, in the form of VolumeUp() and VolumeDown() methods. These can be found in the org.bluez.control interface which you can find at `/org/bluez/<pid of bluetoothd>/hci0/dev_<BD_ADDR>`. I did not have to edit any configuration files to see that interface.

As an example, executing the following will give you the track information:

```
$ qdbus --system org.bluez  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Track

    Album: Lemanis
    Artist: Spaceslug
    Duration: 464945
    Genre: NumberOfTracks: 0
    Title: Proton Lander
    TrackNumber: 0
```

You can press tab after `qdbus --system org.bluez  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/player0` to see all the options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try following: run the script "**simple-endpoint sbcsink**" and then you should be able to make the basic AVRCP functions(ver. 1.0=play pause, next, etc), if you don't know the interfaces for this, uses D-Feet and check it out!!

Comment: are there any tool or command line utilities available instead of the python dbus script ? Any idea ?